# What is the precise meaning of “not of those who have evoked anger or of those who are astray”? (1:7) (Sunni view)

Tags: tafseer, sunni

According to the last verse of Surah al-Fatiha, it says:

> The path of those upon whom You have bestowed favor, not of those who
>   have evoked [Your] anger or of those who are astray. (7)
>
> صِرَاطَ الَّذِينَ أَنْعَمْتَ عَلَيْهِمْ غَيْرِ الْمَغْضُوبِ عَلَيْهِمْ
>   وَلَا الضَّالِّينَ ﴿٧﴾

as it is obvious, its second part means:

> not of those who have evoked [Your] anger or of those who are astray

**but I'd like to know who are them (precisely)? Actually i mean what characteristics they have in accordance with the traditions or scholars' view? (Sunni view)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Narrated 'Adiyy bin Hatim:
that the Prophet (ﷺ) said: "The Jews are those who Allah is wrath with, and the Christians have strayed."

Jami` at-Tirmidhi, Book 47, Hadith 3212.

Comment: Tis a nice answer, but I wish it be more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

I just heard an Arabic scholar talk about this.
Generally speaking
Those you have bestowed anger upon are those people who do not chose the Lord’s path.
Those who do not want the Lord.

Those who went astray are the people that believe in God but they want to get close to him on their terms, their way. A way they invented not the way the Prophet taught us.
Not the way God prefers and loves.

I hope this is clear

Answer (score 0):

There is another explanation, I recently discovered.
An Arabic scholar in Islamic studies, declared that the people who evoke God’s anger are those who corrupt other people and misguide them to destruction of the earth and all living things.
The people who went astray or the misguided people are the ones who became corrupt themselves and destroy themselves.
Because the tendency of the righteous, the prophets and saints has always been to help others and preserve life and the living not destroy.
So most likely the opposite is the unwanted.
Allah knows best